# Certain 64bits causing error with my method Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a method which finds the index of all the set bits in a binary string. It works fine except when the bits are set near the end. Here is the code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    indexSetBits(1101111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L);  
}
    
public static ArrayList<Integer> indexSetBits(long bitboard) {
    
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int count = 0;
    while (bitboard > 0L) {
       if ((bitboard & 1L) == 1L) {
           indices.add(count);
       }
       bitboard >>= 1;
       count++;
    }
    return indices;
}
```

For some reason, when I pass in that 64 bit number as seen in my code, it gives the error: " Long number too large." Though i am sure what i am passing in is a 64 bit number. Is there any way to solve this?

Edit: It was pointed out that I was forgetting the "0b". Whoops!

Now that I remembered that, how would i make sure a method that returns a long, returns it in binary format, in other words how would i pass in a long without explicitly saying "0b".

For example I have this method which returns all the attack bits of a king as a long, and the logic with the bit mainuplation is fine within the actual method.

```
 public long[] calculateKingMoves(int square, long ownSideBitboard,long enemySide, long allPieces){

    /*
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 8, x, 4, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

     */

    //8 possible moves for a king from a given position, unless on a border, under check, or attempting to move into a piece that is
    // under the watch of another piece.
     long kingBitBoard =1L<< square;
     long kingAFile = kingBitBoard & Lookups.fileTables[0];
     long kingHFile = kingBitBoard & Lookups.fileTables[Lookups.fileTables.length-2];

     long move1 = kingAFile <<7;
     long move2 = kingBitBoard <<8;
     long move3 = kingHFile <<9;
     long move4 = kingHFile <<1;

     long move5 = kingHFile >> 7;
     long move6 = kingBitBoard >>8;
     long move7  = kingAFile >>9;
     long move8 = kingAFile >>1;

     long kingPsuedos = move1 | move2| move3| move4| move5| move6| move7| move8;

     long kingMoves = kingPsuedos & ~allPieces;
     long kingAttacks = kingPsuedos & enemySide;

    return new long[]{kingMoves,kingAttacks};




}
```

How would i make sure the two longs returned were in binary format? Instead of just normal longs?

Comment: Yeah: 10L is the number 10, as a Long. 1011010L is the number 1,011,010, as a Long. Adding that L just tells Java that you want a Long instead of an Int, it doesn't convert anything, so: we know that Longs can fit numbers from -2^63 to 2^63-1, which means the bigger number that we can fit in a Long is 19 digits long. However, you're trying to fit a 64 digit (_not bits, digits_) number in a Long... that's not going to work. Did you mean `0b1101111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`?

Comment: For your while loop condition, I would use ``while (bitboard != 0)``. Using >0 will fail if bitboard is negative.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I see what you are saying, I forgot about that. How would i make sure that the long I am passing in would be a binary long without explicitly adding "0b"?

Comment: Not sure that question makes sense: a long is a signed 64 bit long integer number. There is no such thing as a "binary long", there's only one type of long (java doesn't even do unsigned long). If you want to specify a number as a binary pattern, you're going to have to use the `0b` (or `0B`) prefix. Also, numbers are just numbers: once you have them, the code you used to _declare_ them is basically irrelevant: it's a number that is encoded using the bit pattern associated with the declared data type.